# Python evaluation returning False even though individual items are shown as equivalent in interpreter

Tags: python, boolean, return

Why does this not work?

```
def straight(ranks):
    "Return True if the ordered ranks form a 5-card straight."
    return range(max(ranks)-4, max(ranks)+1) == ranks.sort()
```

Assuming ranks is:

```
>>> ranks = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
>>> range(max(ranks)-4, max(ranks)+1)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ranks.sort()
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then why is:

```
>>> range(max(s)-4,max(s)+1) == s.sort()
False
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`s.sort()` returns `None` because it sorts the list in place. Use `sorted(s)`.

```
>>> s = [1,3,2]
>>> repr(s.sort())
'None'
>>> repr(s)
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> repr(sorted(s))
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

Comment: I guess that's why when I tried:

    range(max(s)-4,max(s)+1).reverse()

I had the same issue... it should have been reversed(...)?

Comment: Yes, `reversed()` is the "create a new one" version; `.reverse()` is in-place.

Comment: Yet reversed(ranks) returns: `<listreverseiterator object at 0x1004cb9d0>` instead of the reversed list...

Comment: Yes, you need `list(reversed(ranks))` to turn it into a list.

Comment: @kindall why does it do that instead of behaving like sorted()?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint: Because if you just want to iterate over the list in reverse order, it's faster and uses less memory than creating a whole new list.

Comment: @kindall So reversed returns a kind of generator object? (in this case called a listreverseiterator object)

Answer (score 2):

because `ranks.sort()` is equal to `None`.
use `sorted(ranks)` for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

rank.sort() sorts in the list in place so returns None...use sorted() if you want a list returned.